# How to update a table if values of the attributes are contained within another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, exists

I've got a database like this one:

[image]

I'm trying to create a query that would enable me to update the value of the `status` attribute inside the `incident` table whenever the values of all of these three attributes: `tabor_vatrogasci`, `tabor_policija`, and `tabor_hitna` are contained inside the `izvještaj_tabora` table as a value of the `oznaka_tabora` attribute. If, for example, the values of the `tabor_vatrogasci`, `tabor_policija`, and `tabor_hitna` attributes are 3, 4 and 5 respectively, the `incident` table should be updated if (and only if) 3, 4, and 5 are contained inside the `izvještaj_tabora` table.

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE incident SET status='Otvoren' FROM tabor,izvjestaj_tabora
WHERE (incident.tabor_policija=tabor.oznaka
OR incident.tabor_vatrogasci=tabor.oznaka
OR incident.tabor_hitna=tabor.oznaka)
AND izvjestaj_tabora.oznaka_tabora=tabor.oznaka
AND rezultat_izvjestaja='Riješen' AND
((SELECT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT oznaka_tabora FROM izvjestaj_tabora)
WHERE oznaka_tabora=incident.tabor_policija) OR tabor_policija=NULL) AND
((SELECT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT oznaka_tabora FROM izvjestaj_tabora)
WHERE oznaka_tabora=incident.tabor_vatrogasci) OR tabor_vatrogasci=NULL) AND
((SELECT EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT oznaka_tabora FROM izvjestaj_tabora)
WHERE oznaka_tabora=incident.tabor_hitna) OR tabor_hitna=NULL);
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about "didn't work"?

Comment: @Quassnoi: The update didn't work because the result of at least one of the subqueries was equal to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your *description* the query should look something like this:

```sql
UPDATE incident i
SET    status = 'Otvoren'
WHERE (tabor_policija IS NULL OR
       EXISTS ( 
          SELECT 1 FROM izvjestaj_tabora t
          WHERE  t.oznaka_tabora = i.tabor_policija
          )
       )
AND   (tabor_vatrogasci IS NULL OR
       EXISTS ( 
          SELECT 1 FROM izvjestaj_tabora t
          WHERE  t.oznaka_tabora = i.tabor_vatrogasci
          )
       )
AND   (tabor_hitna IS NULL OR
       EXISTS ( 
          SELECT 1 FROM izvjestaj_tabora t
          WHERE  t.oznaka_tabora = i.tabor_hitna
          )
       )
```

<sub>I wonder though, why the connecting table `tabor` is irrelevant to the operation.</sub>

Among other things you fell victim to two widespread misconceptions:

1)

```sql
tabor_policija=NULL
```

This expression **aways results in `NULL`**. Since `NULL` is considered "unknown", if you compare it to anything, the outcome is "unknown" as well. I quote [the manual on Comparison Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html):

> Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not "equal to" NULL.
>   (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known
>   whether two unknown values are equal.)

2)

```sql
EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT oznaka_tabora FROM ...)
```

In an [**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join `SELECT` items are completely irrelevant. (I use `SELECT 1` instead). As the term implies, only *existence* is checked. The expression returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, `SELECT` items are ignored. It is particularly pointless to add a `DISTINCT` clause there.

Answer (score 2):

Asuming `INCIDENT.OZNAKA` is the key and you need all 3 to be ralated for the event to open (I am Slovenian that why I understand ;) )

```
UPDATE incident
SET status='Otvoren' 
WHERE oznaka in (
    SELECT DISTINCT i.oznaka
    FROM incident i
        INNER JOIN izvještaj_tabora t1 ON i.tabor_vatrogasci = t1.oznaka_tabora
        INNER JOIN izvještaj_tabora t2 ON i.tabor_policija = t2.oznaka_tabora
        INNER JOIN izvještaj_tabora t3 ON i.tabor_hitna = t3.oznaka_tabora
    WHERE t1.rezultat_izvjestaja='Riješen' AND t2.rezultat_izvjestaja='Riješen' AND t3.rezultat_izvjestaja='Riješen'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm trying to apply this when the value of one of the attributes ("tabor_vatrogasci", "tabor_policija", "tabor_hitna") may be equal to `NULL`. How do I write this down in that case?